# Parallel Array Processing C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on an assignment with an input file that needs to be placed into a parallel array. The good news is I have no syntax errors, but I am getting some logical errors that are stumping me. The purpose of the program is to sort a text file consisting of bowling matchup. There are two teams: blue and white with the same number of players. The program is to output the winner of the matchup by totaling up their scores and displaying their individual scores. If you can give me some direction where I messed up, it would help me greatly.

**UPDATE**
    I made some changes to my code, but am having one last syntax error I cannot figure out. It has to deal with printArray. If someone can help, I'd appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int LENGTH = 10;

// declaration of functions sumArray() and printArray()
int sumArray(int [], int);

string printArray(string, string [], int [], int);

// declaration of main program
int main()
{
  string blue_members[LENGTH], white_members[LENGTH];
  int blue_scores[LENGTH], white_scores[LENGTH];

  // 1) connect to the input file
  ifstream fin("bowling.txt");
  // declare arrays below
  string Team, Member;
  int Score;

  // 2) initialize array accumulators to zero
  int blue = 0;
  int white = 0;

  // 3) display a descriptive message
  cout << "This program reads the lines from the file bowling.txt to determine\n"
       << "the winner of a bowling match.  The winning team, members and scores\n"
       << "are displayed on the monitor.\n\n";

  // 4) attempt to input the first line of the file
  fin >> Member >> Team >> Score;
  // 5) test ifstream.eof() condition
  while (!fin.eof())
    {
      // 6) test team color is blue
      if (Team == "Blue")
    {
      // 7) then store blue member and score
      blue_scores[blue] = Score;
      blue_members[blue] = Member;

      // 8) increase blue array accumulator
      blue++;
    }
      // 9) else store white member and score
      else
    {
      white_scores[white] = Score;
      white_members[white] = Member;

      // 10) increase white array accumulator
      white++;
    }
      // 11) attempt to input next line from file
      fin >> Member >> Team >> Score;
    }

  // 12) if blue team score is larger

  if (sumArray(blue_scores, blue) > sumArray(white_scores, white))
    {
    // 13 then display blue team as winner with the team
    printArray(Team, blue_members, blue_scores, Score);
    }

  // 14) else display white team as winner with the team
  else
    {
    printArray(Team, white_members, white_scores, Score);
    }
}

// implement function sumArray() below
int sumArray(int array_name[], int array_end)
{
  // 1. initialize accumulator to 0
  int sum = 0;

  // 2. loop over initialized array indices
  for (int i = 0; i < array_end; i++)

    //      3. increase accumulator by indexed array element
    sum += array_name[i];

  //   4. return accumulator
  return sum;
}

// implement function printArray() below
void printArray(string team_name, string array_name [], int array_score [], int array_end)
{
  // 1. display  the team name as the winner
  cout << setw(1) << "Winning Team: " << team_name<< endl;
  cout << setw(5) << "Player" << setw(7) << "Score" << endl;

  //   2. loop over initialized array indices
  for (int i = 0; i < array_end; i++)
    {
      //      3. display member and score for that array index
      cout << setw(3) << array_name[i] 
       << setw(6) << setfill(' ') << array_score[i] 
       << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Imran, It's stretching the purpose of this site a bit to ask a question as broad as this. But, it's possible, that if you add more info explaining what you expect and what you are actually getting, OR, simplify the program down to the essence of the problem you are having, you may get some helpful responses.

Comment: It would be nice if you would react to answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing what you read from the file in `Member`, `Team`, and `Score`. Then you are assigning to that variables whatever is in your arrays.

You need to change

```
Score = blue_scores[blue];
Member = blue_members[blue];
```

To

```
blue_scores[blue] = Score;
blue_members[blue] = Member;
```

Same for white team. Done that, what you read from the file is now stored in your arrays and your code should now output the expected results.

**UPDATE**

Also, your call for `printArray` shoud be:

```
printArray("Blue", blue_members, blue_scores, LENGTH);
```

And `printArray` returns nothing, so change it to `void` too.